# Java to SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a remote SQL Server DB from a Java application without success.

I am able to successfully connect to that SQL Server instance from a SQL client for Mac called SQLPro for MSSQL
[image]

However, if I try to connect from the Java application using those same credentials, I always get a Login failed error, this is the code snipper I'm using:

```
String connectionUrl =
        "jdbc:sqlserver://some-host:1433;"
                + "database=DBName;"
                + "user=GLOBAL\\user;"
                + "password=somepassword;"
                + "encrypt=true;"
                + "trustServerCertificate=true;"
                + "loginTimeout=30;";

ResultSet resultSet = null;

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {

    // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
    String selectSql = "select * from R2.LABEL_MASTER";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

    // Print results from select statement
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2) + " " + resultSet.getString(3));
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm using this gradle dependency for the sql server jdbc driver

implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '10.2.0.jre11'

One important point is that I am not on a Windows machine, which should not be an issue, as I mentioned, I am able to connect to the SQL Server using an SQL client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect using Windows Auth with app-provided credentials, you must [configure the connection to use NTLM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Using%20NTLM%20Authentication%20to%20connect%20to%20SQL%20Server,...%205%20Security%20risks.%20...%206%20See%20also).  The current connection string is for SQL Auth.